# How to use JavaScript loop through json array?

Tags: javascript, json, fancybox

How I can use a for loop through this codes?

```
$(".open-slide").on('click', function(){
var ddd = ['/cheetahadmin/Templates/uploads/Agency/slides/agenc-contact.jpg', '/cheetahadmin/Templates/uploads/Agency/slides/agency-about.jpg', '/cheetahadmin/Templates/uploads/Agency/slides/agency-index.jpg'];
$.fancybox.open([

                for(var i=0; i<=ddd.length; i++){
                    {
                        src  : ddd[i],
                        opts : {
                            caption : 'Example Caption'
                        }
                    },
                }

            ], {
                loop : false,
                toolbar: false
            });
        });
```

This codes give me an error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for
and I know I have mistake, but I don't know how I can fix this.

Comment: There is no JSON here and you you are looping one too many iterations because of the `<=`, it should just be `<` And the whole for loop makes ZERO sense.... You can not just loop inside of an object, what you are doing is not what what you think is happening...

Comment: You can't jam code in between square brackets like that, javascript is expecting the first value (token) of the array you're defining rather than a for loop.

Comment: I know I have mistake, How I can push my array data inside brackets dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Since a call to array.map returns another array, and your start array is easily mapped to your desired array, a `.map` solution can be used in place rather than building the array first and storing it into another variable, and then calling `.open` passing that variable as a parameter.

```
$.fancybox.open(ddd.map(function (el) {
  return {
    src: el, 
    opts: { 
      caption: 'Example Caption' 
    }
  };
}), {
  loop : false,
  toolbar: false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array of objects like:

```
var arrOptions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ddd.length; i++) {
  arrOptions.push({
    src: ddd[i],
    opts: { caption: 'Example Caption' }
  });
}
```

and then pass it to `fancybox` like:

```
$.fancybox.open(arrOptions, {
  loop: false,
  toolbar: false
});
```

Comment: Thanks, short and helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert an array of strings, into an array of objects. What you are doing is not going to produce that. You need to pull the code outside of the array. Now you could do it with a for loop and push to build an array

```js
var ddd = ['/cheetahadmin/Templates/uploads/Agency/slides/agenc-contact.jpg', '/cheetahadmin/Templates/uploads/Agency/slides/agency-about.jpg', '/cheetahadmin/Templates/uploads/Agency/slides/agency-index.jpg'];

var formatted = [];
for (var i=0; i<ddd.length; i++) {
  formatted.push({
    src: ddd[i],
    opts: {
      caption: 'Example Caption'
    }
  })
}
console.log(formatted)
```

But most people would skip the for loop and use map()

```js
var ddd = ['/cheetahadmin/Templates/uploads/Agency/slides/agenc-contact.jpg', '/cheetahadmin/Templates/uploads/Agency/slides/agency-about.jpg', '/cheetahadmin/Templates/uploads/Agency/slides/agency-index.jpg'];

var formatted = ddd.map(function(val) {

  return {
    src: val,
    opts: {
      caption: 'Example Caption'
    }
  }

});

console.log(formatted);
```

Then you would just do

```
$.fancybox.open(formatted, { /* other code */ });
```